# Creating an octagon

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am very new to webgl and I am working on an octagon that eventually will change color on refresh but I am having issues with my color buffer and just color in general. If I were to go to the html doc and just set the Frag_color manually, the octagon works.

This is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 aColor;
varying vec4 vColor;
void
main()
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
    vColor = aColor;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 vColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="octagon.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript file

```
var gl;
var points;
var pi = 3.1415;
var rad = 2*pi/360;
var r = 0.5;
var colors = [];
var vertices = [];

window.onload = function init()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    vertices.push(0.0);
    vertices.push(0.0);
    colors.push(1.0);
    colors.push(0.0);
    colors.push(0.0);
    colors.push(1.0);
    for(var theta = 0; theta <= 360; theta+=45)
    {
        vertices.push(r*Math.cos(rad*theta));
        vertices.push(r*Math.sin(rad*theta));
        colors.push(1.0);
        colors.push(0.0);
        colors.push(0.0);
        colors.push(1.0);
    }
    //  Configure WebGL

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );
    
    // Load the data into the GPU
    
    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    
    

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
    
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
    
    var colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    var aColor = g1.getAttribLocation(program, "aColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( aColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aColor);
    
    render();
};


function render() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 10 );
}
```

Comment: You have typo in your code: `var aColor = g1.getAttribLocation(program, "aColor");`

Comment: Łukasz is right; and, beside that `1` that should be a `l`, everything is correct. Here I created a code pen that uses `theta` to assign random color to vertices and everything is working as expected: https://codepen.io/dawken/pen/LYaadKL?editors=0010